# How to display a contact in Android

Tags: android

```
//Look up a contact by phone number and display it.

Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", vc.cellphone, null));
startActivity(intent);
```

This code works as intended. However, if there is more than one contact with that number, we get a crash.
When the crash happens. Logcat says:

```
04-04 05:26:34.764: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.android.contacts.action.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT dat=tel:078551212 cmp=com.android.contacts/.ui.ShowOrCreateActivity }
04-04 05:26:35.834: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH cmp=com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity (has extras) }
04-04 05:26:36.064: INFO/ContactsListActivity(276): Called with action: android.intent.action.SEARCH
04-04 05:26:36.804: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Displayed activity com.android.contacts/.ui.ShowOrCreateActivity: 1999 ms (total 1999 ms)
04-04 05:26:36.814: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Displayed activity com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity: 858 ms (total 858 ms)
04-04 05:26:43.153: ERROR/CursorWindow(276): Bad request for field slot 0,6. numRows = 2, numColumns = 6
04-04 05:26:43.173: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM
04-04 05:26:43.173: WARN/dalvikvm(276): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-04 05:26:43.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 6 failed
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.contacts.ContactsListActivity.getContactUri(ContactsListActivity.java:1564)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.contacts.ContactsListActivity.getSelectedUri(ContactsListActivity.java:1598)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.contacts.ContactsListActivity.onListItemClick(ContactsListActivity.java:1255)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:312)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-04 05:26:43.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the correct content and what do you get in the wrong content?

Comment: Correct content is a contact with the cell phone number required ie vc.cellphone. Wrong content is an activity titled 'Contacts' with two entries labelled '2' both of which produce a crash when clicked.

Comment: Is that in the emulator or in an actual phone? What does the logcat tell you?

Comment: phone and emulator, both 2.1 update1, question edited to show logcat output.

Comment: I can't find why it is unable to find "row 0 col 6". Just a silly question, tough: did you try with a phone number that does not start with a zero?

Comment: @Tom check the updated answer with the last link to the SO Q&A

Answer (score 2):

**After the question updates, most of this answer became irrelevant, but the links may still be useful for others having issues with the contacts, so instead of deleting the answer, I decided to keep those:**

---

Links to Q&A in SO:

[How can I launch the 'Add Contact' activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895206/how-can-i-launch-the-add-contact-activity-in-android)

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

[Launching external application from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977243/launching-external-application-from-my-app)

**This one deals with exactly your problem**: [Android - Show list of contacts with same phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610320/android-show-list-of-contacts-with-same-phone-number) . There is an answer there by **DEzra** suggesting to use "Android content provider api in combination with a SQL query"

---

Links to the android API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Comment: Thanks for all the links, I'm afraid none of them have resulted in a fix though.

Comment: No problem, but if you fixed it, please consider writing what you did as an answer and accepting it, so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Nope, no fix yet. If anyone else is up against this one then Android source code might shed some light...